# Overflow property causes part of code to disappear?

Tags: css

I'm trying to put a scrollbar inside my div tag yet when I do, the arrow on the side of it disappears. Is there are way to fix this?
Live preview [here](https://yume.neocities.org/test1.html).

The bubble is supposed to look like [this](https://yume.neocities.org/test2.html), but with a scrollbar in it of course.

```
.bubble {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.bubble:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px; 
    top: 24px;
    bottom: auto; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 24px 12px 0px;
    border-color: transparent #000000;
}
.bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 23px 11px 0px;
    border-color: transparent #ffffff;
    display: block;
    width : 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below content div inside bubble div.

Put content of bubble div inside the below div and add the style..

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Inside style :

```
.content{
 height:70px;
 overflow-y:scroll;}
```

HOPE IT HELPS

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the content of the bubble inside a div, and put **overflow: scroll** on that child div, rather than on the entire bubble.